# В чём разница между переменными var a и var $a в  javascript?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день!

Всё чаще в js скриптах сталкиваюсь с обявлением переменных с использованием знака доллара, т.е. вместо простого объявления **var A** я вижу **var $A**, и в дальнеймем по коду обращения к этой переменной то так **$A**, то вот так **$(A)**. Вот, например, кусочек из скрипта:

```
var forms = function(){
    $('.js_form').each(function(){ 
        var $form = $(this),
            $customField = $form.find('[data-error]'),
            customFieldRulls = {};
        var zIndexs = function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('label.error').each(function(i){
                    $(this).css({'z-index':'50'-i})
                });                     
            },200)
        };
```

Используются как обычные переменные, так и "переменные с долларом". Не пойму, в чём между ними разница? Это просто для удобства делается, или это что-то дополнительное с функциональной точки зрения даёт?

Comment: Если говорить в контектсте jQuery, то в большинстве случаев, таким образом показывают, что в переменной находится именно **объект jQuery**. Несёт только смысловую нагрузку и удобней для понимания того, с чем работаешь.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Не могу быть уверенным на все 146%, однако есть ощущение, что значком доллара тут отмечается тот факт, что значение переменной получено с помощью jQuery-селектора. Тогда как прочие, обычные js-переменные идут без этого префикса. В принципе, выглядит достаточно логично - js - язык с динамической типизацией, и понять по имени переменной, что в ней хранится, бывает не всегда возможно. Поэтому префикс в виде доллара облегчает это понимание.

Однако, вне зависимости от того, верно ли мое предположение, или нет, какого-то нового функционала объявление "с долларом" не несет - в js это такой же символ, который можно использовать в названиях идентификаторов, что и прочие

Comment: 101% уже есть.

Comment: В *моей* конвенции $XXX - это любая выборка элементов.

Comment: Всем спасибо, теперь будет легче воспринимать эти скрипты. ))

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем так. Исходя из последних спецификаций jQuery:

```
<div id="selector"></div>
function ready() {
  var selector = $('#selector');
  var selector = $('#selector').context;
  var $selector = $('#selector');
}
window.onload = ready;
```

В первом случае selector вернет **[object Object]**

Во втором **[object HTMLDocument]** (так, для полноты картины)

А в третьем **[object HTMLDivElement]**

Коротко говоря, третий вариант сработает как **document.getElementById('selector ');** на чистом JS.

А там уже смотрите сами, кому с чем и как работать нужно.